# JAR Bindings Library issues

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to build a C# JAR library, using Visual Studio Community 2015 (I've also tried this on Visual Studio 2013 Professional, with the same results), to allow me to use the built-in IR hardware scanner on a Mitac Android (4.2.2) device. I've already successfully written one app, but this was just using Bluetooth comms for printing.

Mitac have supplied a couple of JAR files, so I've attempted to follow the bindings project instructions fro here: 
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/,

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, I keep getting the error:

```
Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       "generator.exe" exited with code -532462766.    ClassLibrary2 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Bindings.targets 413
```

further output:

```
1>  Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.
1>  Parameter name: startIndex
1>     at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
1>     at MonoDroid.Generation.Method.CalculateEventName(Func 2 checkNameDuplicate)
1>     at MonoDroid.Generation.InterfaceGen.GenerateEventsOrPropertiesForListener(StreamWriter sw, String indent, CodeGenerationOptions opt, ClassGen target)
1>     at MonoDroid.Generation.ClassGen.GenMethods(StreamWriter sw, String indent, CodeGenerationOptions opt)
1>     at MonoDroid.Generation.ClassGen.Generate(StreamWriter sw, String indent, CodeGenerationOptions opt, GenerationInfo gen_info)
1>     at MonoDroid.Generation.ClassGen.Generate(CodeGenerationOptions opt, GenerationInfo gen_info)
1>     at Xamarin.Android.Binder.CodeGenerator.Run(CodeGeneratorOptions options)
1>     at Xamarin.Android.Binder.CodeGenerator.Main(String[] args)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Bindings.targets(413,5): error MSB6006: "generator.exe" exited with code -532462766.
```

The project output is here: [output.txt](http://m.uploadedit.com/ba3s/1468490735985.txt).

Any help or pointers would be greatly welcomed, thanks!

Comment: That error looks familiar, are you trying to bind Mitac `cell_150915_cb.jar` ? Is it that one with a bunch of Smack jars?

Comment: Yes, I am, the other JARs are: 
asmack-android-17-0.8.10.jar, 
core-2.3.0.jar, 
zbar.jar and 
zip4j_1.3.1.jar.

You had any luck with this?

Comment: Yes (and no)... the error you are getting is kind-of a bug. You can get around it by adding a transform of `<remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.mitac.cell.device']" />` Then you will actually get to "real errors" in the binding. It took around 70/80 lines of transforms to get things sorted out and getting a binding project for that MiTac jar.

Comment: I see what you mean, 1 error and 130 warnings now! Ouch!

Comment: So not sure how to resolve stuff like this:
`Warning  Couldn't load class com/mitac/cell/network/McXmppClient : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jivesoftware/smack/ConnectionListener BindingClassLibrary`

Comment: You might do well to look over these two trouble shooting guides for binding jars: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings/ and https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb